# when executing SSH command from jenkins nvm not found

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins, nvm

I am working on an express app and trying to deploy it on ec2 with Jenkins.
I used the terminal to install nvm and it's working fine.

In Jenkins, I used Publish Over SSH Plugin to upload the build to ec2 with the same **user** but it fails on npm install command.

I checked .bashrc and verified the nvm installation.

When I run printenv command from the shell it shows nvm in PATH

> PATH=/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

But when I run it from Jenkins job it is not there

> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
>   _=/usr/bin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins node / agent / slave launches a [non-interactive shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html), which skips the user .bashrc, only the system ( in /etc) profile. There are various workarounds beyond editing the system defaults.

We use a combination of [SSH Slaves Setup](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=58002132#content/view/58002132) plugin and [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=57999800#content/view/57999800).

YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround for snaps in general (this problem actually affects all snap applications) would be to modify the PATH environment variable from the Jenkins Node Configuration. By doing this, every job running on the node sees the modified PATH variable. The following settings prepend "/snap/bin" to PATH:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is that you run something like 'echo whoami' in your jenkins script to make sure you are your current user. If so, you can change the user (if running as root user, for example).
From what you have described, it seems to me that the users are not the same.

Comment: I did that too and its the same user.

Comment: Ok, so I have a solution (I know it might not be ideal, but it probably might work): export the path in the jenkink script. Something like: export PATH=/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin:$PATH